# What is the web development tool called?

Tags: html, css

I remember I've seen something like "when the mouse hovers on some texts, it shows a fancy list of texts with fancy effects, and when the mouse hovers away, the fancy list disappears." 
What exactly is this function called?
which library does this function come from?
How can I add this function into my website?
thx!

Comment: Please provide link to example - or attach a screenshot of what you are referring to.

Comment: Do you mean a tooltip?

Comment: I guess its like a tooltip? but it's much fancier than that. I'm still trying to find one. I'll attack it ASAP I find it.

Comment: Stack Overflow is not supposed to be a game of 20 questions, nor a guessing game regarding third-party components. See [help/on-topic], where it notes *Questions asking us to recommend or **find** a book, tool, **software library**, tutorial or **other off-site resource** are **off-topic** for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.* (emphasis mine)

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft Office's documentation refers to it as the "Mini toolbar": https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Add-formatting-to-your-document-by-using-the-Mini-toolbar-47012F83-B553-40A9-B7DE-F038876F4DB3

It has no direct relation to web-editing, and I'm not aware of any web development or web publishing tools that include this UI feature out-of-the-box (though there's probably a VS Extension for it by now).

Note that such a feature only works in WYSIWYG mode, and the past 25 years of web-development history shows that the WYSIWYG paradigm does not generally work for HTML, which probably why such a feature is not widespread.